# what is Promotional and Feature graphic in Android Market/Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

What does it mean and need whether we are uploading our app into the market? Please Explain or give me a related links.

Comment: You can generate android feature graphics from this [link](http://uncaughterror.com/tools/android-feature-graphic-generator/)

Answer (score 24):

> In market client on phones at least
>   featured apps with high ratings get to
>   display the promotional graphic.
>
> This is the one that shows up on top
>   even before you start searching the
>   market for a specific app.

See this <strike>[answer](http://www.google.fm/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=111b1bd2ecd27933&hl=en)</strike> from Android market forum.

**Edited**: One of the google employee gives some clarifications <strike>[here](http://www.google.fm/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=1fe1d6bfdc0229db&hl=en)</strike>

**Update**: Both links above are now broken but the detailed information can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?visit_id=1-636231988274072661-3129297580&rd=1)

> Selected applications have the ability
>   to be featured atop their respective
>   categories. This is not a guaranteed
>   feature, but uploading promotional
>   graphics is something that we
>   recommend.

Comment: That covers promotional graphic, but not feature

Comment: The URLs are now broken: 'There is no group named “android-market”'

Comment: Note that "The promo graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the Android OS (earlier than 4.0)." (Adding info here as it is the top answer)

Answer (score 7):

I know there were several perfect answers but I found this page useful as well !

from: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Quote from the site:

> The Feature Graphic is used for promotions on Google Play. While this
>   graphic is not required to save and publish your Store Listing, it is
>   required in order to be featured on Google Play.

Commentary:

To be clear, these "promotions" are chosen at Google's discretion. Even though excellent the "This is a test" app demonstration (above) shows the Feature graphic used in common areas of the **outdated** "Android Market", this is no longer the case with today's "Play Store".

Quote from the site:

> The Promo Graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the
>   Android OS (earlier than 4.0). This image is not required to save and
>   publish your Store Listing.

Commentary:

It appears that this is also at Google's discretion and not always used as the "This is a test" demo suggests. Even though an older device may not get an update to their Android version, the "Android Market" update bringing them to a modern version of "Play Store" should be available.

Comment: Okay Richard, I'll follow these advices next time, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

I found this nice [write-up](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1078870) that clears it up pretty nicely:

> The different graphic assets we request are used to highlight and promote your application in Android Market, and possibly other Google-owned properties. If you’d like to restrict the marketing of your app to just Android Market, you have the option of opting-out of marketing by selecting the "Marketing Opt-Out" in the Developer Console.

```
Screenshots (Required):
We require 2 screenshots.
Use: Displayed on the details page for your application in Android Market.
You may upload up to 8 screenshots.
Specs: 320w x 480h, 480w x 800h, or 480w x 854h; 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha) Full bleed, no border in art.
Tips:
Landscape thumbnails are cropped, but we preserve the image’s full size and aspect ratio if the user opens it up on market client.
High Resolution Application Icon (Required):
Use: In various locations in Android Market.
Does not replace your launcher icon.
Specs: 512x512, 32-bit PNG with alpha; Max size of 1024KB.
Tips:
This does not replace your launcher icon, but should be a higher-fidelity, higher-resolution version of your application icon.
Same safe-frame as current launcher guidelines, just scaled up:
Full Asset: 512 x 512 px.
Circle or non-square icons: 426 x 426 px, centered within the PNG.
Square Icons: 398 x 398 px.
Drop shadow: black, 75% opaque, 90 degrees down, distance of 14px, size of 36px.
Tweak as necessary to fit icon style (e.g., Google Maps icon has a drop shadow of varying height).
Promotional Graphic (Optional):
Use: In various locations in Android Market.
Specs: 180w x 120h, 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha), Full bleed, no border in art.
Feature Graphic (Optional):
Use: The featured section in Android Market. Will be downsized to mini or micro.
Specs: 1024w x 500h, 24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha) with no transparency
Tips:
Use a safe frame of 924x400 (50 pixel of safe padding on each side). All the important content of the graphic should be within this safe frame. Pixels outside of this safe frame may be cropped for stylistic purposes.
If incorporating text, use large font sizes, and keep the graphic simple, as this graphic may be scaled down from its original size.
This graphic may be displayed alone without the app icon.
Video Link (Optional):
Specs: Enter the URL to a YouTube video showcasing your app.
Tip:
Short videos (30 seconds - 2 minutes) highlighting the top features of your app work best.
```

Comment: Nice copy/paste from the Android Market docs, but it still doesn't really explain what a promotional graphic is or where is shows up.

Answer (score 5):

Featured graphics guidelines:

http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

List of graphics assets for your application:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870

You could also check our blog post summarizing all graphical assets for both Android and iOS:

http://www.skoumal.net/en/how-to-prepare-graphical-design-for-mobile-app/

Answer (score 3):

It's here
http://www.android.com/market/featured.html
Weirdly, you don't get to that page if you start from the android market and hit "featured".
Mary

Answer (score 2):

> Promo graphic
>
> The promo graphic is used for promotions on older versions of the Android OS (earlier than 4.0). This image is not required to submit an update for your Store Listing.
>
> Requirements
>
> - JPG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)
> - Dimensions: 180px by 120px

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Google Play 4.9, the app info display has been changed and the promo graphic is displayed at the top.

The promo graphic will be required soon.

The promo text has turned into a short description and is now shown on the main info page, before the user presses it to view the full description.