# What is the "Feature Graphic" for Android apps?

Tags: android, publish, google-play, graphic

I simply cannot find any documentation on what I'm supposed to include in my Feature Graphic. The only info listed is:

1024w x 500h

24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha)

Will be downsized to mini or micro

But what content should it include? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436581/what-is-promotional-and-feature-graphic-in-android-market)

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a duplicate of that question since that question already has a selected answer and the answer only refers to the promo graphic and not the feature graphic.

Comment: Correct, I had seen the other question, but there isn't an answer for the content of the Feature Graphic, just the promo.

Comment: Google's official post on the subject: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

Comment: I'm using this tool to generate [android feature graphics](http://uncaughterror.com/tools/android-feature-graphic-generator/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

EDIT:  Google announced the web version of the Android Market earlier today.  It appears that the "feature graphic" is used (in a smaller size) for the top features (see large images near the top: http://market.android.com/) and at the top of individual app pages.

The little I found was this:

- Use a safe frame of 924x400 (50 pixel
  of safe padding on each side). All
  the important content of the graphic
  should be within this safe frame.
  Pixels outside of this safe frame may
  be cropped for stylistic purposes.
- If incorporating text, use large font
  sizes, and keep the graphic simple,
  as this graphic may be scaled down
  from its original size.
- This graphic may be displayed alone
  without the app icon.

Based on the size and name alone, I guess that it's most likely to be used for your app if it is featured and the large size is so that it looks good on the tablets that are coming out.

Comment: Thank you for the extra technical info, I'll definitely keep the safe frame in mind. What I'm looking for though is some direction on content. What type of info should the graphic contain?

Comment: I don't believe Google has given specific direction on that, but the safest bet would be to stick to branding graphics since it may be resized (which would make any smaller text illegible).

Comment: Here's more details from Google about what to include and where the Feature Graphic gets used: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html

Answer (score 20):

You can add app icon, app title, tagline, photo that represents the idea behind app, etc...
Look at attached images for better idea.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The feature graphic is no longer optional.

See this [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20Feature%20graphic&tbs=isz:m&tbm=isch) for many examples.

[android-market-featured-image](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html) discusses content do's and don'ts.

Answer (score 0):

It's that flashy image on the top of the (new) market, for when your app is featured there. I didn't bother with it for my app :)

Comment: I don't have any devices running AndroidOS 3.2 (Gingerbread), so I can't see what graphic you are talking about. What kind of content should it have? Is it just a graphical advertisement? Is it supposed to detail the feature set of the app? Should it mostly just be a logo and some iconography?

Comment: it's now required when publishing an app.