# Featured and Promotion Graphic Android play store

Tags: google-play

I have been trying to figure out where Promotion and Featured graphic shows up. But I am not able to find any use for it. Not even a app that uses it. All I find is the HD app icon and the screen shots.

I have looked at [thisisatest](http://xayin.com/thisisatest.html), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436581/what-is-promotional-and-feature-graphic-in-android-market-play-store). When I see Android phone via Play Store, I dont see the Promotion and Featured images. When I see the website, there too I am not able to find use of these images.

Has something changed in Play Store over the years (Since July 2012) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store received a major redesign about mid-July, 2013, and the feature graphic, which used to provide a banner of sorts for the listing page (and was required in order to be featured) seems to have disappeared in the process.