# Is featured and promo graphic even used any more on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I can't seem to figure out if the featured and promo graphic still is used on Play? It seems to me the new design only relies on the app icon. Anyone that can prove me wrong?

Comment: please have look here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436581/what-is-promotional-and-feature-graphic-in-android-market-play-store

Comment: @SankarGanesh answer old and outdated

Comment: Nowdays all the app relies on app icon only, apart from Szymon answer.

Comment: @SankarGanesh source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Google Play, Apps, then Editor's Choice. They are still used there.

Comment: Yes on the phones they are still used there, any other places?

Comment: Not sure. That's the only spot I know of.

Comment: I'll award as answer if nothing else shows up :)

Comment: Is this still the case? I don't see it.  It looks like the Editor's Choice list is showing the Feature graphic